# Enter Hyphen and Decimal in single keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an Edittext, in this values can be entered as 123-34.20 or 123.45 Until every thing good  till here.

a) Where as InputType i have given as **android:inputType="phone"** every thing works fine for me. But some of Device like Samsung S4 is asking to Sym the keyBoard and then Enter Hyphen and Decimal.

b) I want to show Hyphen and Decimal in same key board with out using Sym.

@Note: I Have also tried using  **android:inputType="numberDecimal"** Nothing works for me

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers are using their own (broken) keyboards, so the result of inputType can vary depending on which phone you are using as you noticed. If you have to make it work for all the phones then I suggest that you remove the inputType so that the user can access the complete keyboard no matter which phone he's using. 
Now, as the user will be able to enter a whole bunch of unwanted symbols, I suggest that you implement a string validation on your editText.

Comment: Then maybe you should try to have a look at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2497237&__utma=248941774.636334738.1378456606.1383798151.1395050823.4&__utmb=248941774.1.10.1395050823&__utmc=248941774&__utmx=-&__utmz=248941774.1395050823.4.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=34113442 and implement your own keyboard layout

Comment: I have tried custom KeyBoard, Then my issue is Edittext is Hiding for me. Even though i have used adjustResize in Manifest

Comment: Then you should try to have a deeper understanding of the keyboard (maybe by reading http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) but I'm quite sure that custom keyboard is the way to go to ensure that the keyboard will show only the wanted symbols across the different phones

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can't be achieved using any kinda input methods...But I have seen a keyboard in the app called [Touchpal Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5). Which is the image that I have shown.

So you can't just do things like this unless you create you own custom keyboard for your textfield in your app.

You might wanna have a look at this link:
[Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

[image: TouchPal Keyboard - Showing all numbers, hyphen, dot"."]